# Openvpn register-dns error despite using last version

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn

I have the following error that prevents me from setting up my dns properly when running my openvpn config through the command line:

`Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: register-dns (2.4.4)`

From what I have found so far, this kind of error usually comes from the use of an outdated version of openvpn. But I have installed the last version of openvpn available atm (2.4.4).

Here is my openvpn config file:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher XXX
auth XXX
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote vpn.com xxxx udp
auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo yes
auth-nocache
<ca>
</ca>
setenv CLIENT_CERT 0
<tls-auth>
</tls-auth>
key-direction 1
```

I don't see which instruction returns this error nor why it is not fixed since I have updated my openvpn package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to work around this issue by adding the following lines that I found in another old config file:

```
script-security 2
up   /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you're getting is referring to an option that is being pushed from the server side. Because we only have the client configuration to look at, it's hard to say what incorrect values the server is trying to push: do you have access to the server configuration (or the client log file, if you set that to DEBUG logging level)?